# I cannot get over 50% accuracy on my test data in this simple CNN Tensorflow Keras model for image classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, image-classification, overfitting-underfitting

The code is as follows. I have a highly imbalanced dataset for chest x rays with heart enlargement. The images are separated into a training folder split into positive for cardiomegaly and negative for cardiomegaly subfolders (467 pos images and ~20,000 neg). (Then I have a testing folder with two subfolders (300 pos, 300 neg). Each time I test I keep getting a 50% accuracy with the eval method below. When I look at the predictions it is always that they are all one class (normally negative), however if I give the positive values a very high weight (1000+ compared to the negative values 1) the model will flip and say that they are all instead positive. This leads me to believe it is overfitting but all my attempts to resolve this have come up with issues.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import skimage as sk
import skimage.io as skio
import skimage.transform as sktr
import skimage.filters as skfl
import skimage.feature as skft
import skimage.color as skcol
import skimage.exposure as skexp
import skimage.morphology as skmr
import skimage.util as skut
import skimage.measure as skme
import sklearn.model_selection as le_ms
import sklearn.decomposition as le_de
import sklearn.discriminant_analysis as le_di
import sklearn.preprocessing as le_pr
import sklearn.linear_model as le_lm
import sklearn.metrics as le_me
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
classNames = ["trainpos","trainneg"]
testclassNames = ["testpos", "test"]
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    './data/trainup/',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    class_names=classNames,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(256, 256),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    interpolation='gaussian',
    follow_links=False,
)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    './data/trainup/',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    class_names=classNames,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(256, 256),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=23,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    interpolation='gaussian',
    follow_links=False,
)

test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    './data/testup/',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    class_names=testclassNames,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(256, 256),
    shuffle=True,
    interpolation='gaussian',
    follow_links=False,
)

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(256, 256, 1)),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 4, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 4, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
])

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

class_weight = {0: 29, 1: 1}

history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=5,
   class_weight=class_weight
)
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_ds)
print("Test Loss: ", test_loss)
print("Test Accuracy: ", test_accuracy)
```

19/19 [==============================] - 7s 376ms/step - loss: 3.4121 - accuracy: 0.5000
Test Loss:  3.4121198654174805
Test Accuracy:  0.5

I have tried updating the learning rate to values between 0.1 and 0.00001, adding epochs, removing epochs, changing to SGP for the optimizer, attempting to unpack the test_ds after subscripting it gave me the error that it is a batchdataset and can't be subscripted. This then shows me that the test_ds is giving me ~19 tensors of 32 images each except the last one which has about 25. I then wanted to predict each of these images individually and get the results because it looked like it was grouping all 32 (or 25 for the last one) together and then predicting based on that but that led me down rabbitholes that I haven't come out of with results. Tried many other things I can't fully remember normally tweaking the model itself or adding data augmentation (I am using tensorflow 2.3 as this is for a class with a repeating assignment so the data augmentation cannot be done with the current docs (mostly just vertical and horizontal changes in this version from what I can tell)

Comment: Maybe use `20000/467` as weight for class 0, so that your model can't "cheat" and improve the loss by choosing one class only.

Comment: Usually 3 (or some other odd number) is used for conv kernel size, not 4

Comment: The task seems pretty difficult, so maybe the model is too small and that's why it will be underfitting

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to eliminate the imbalance to begin with. You have 467 positive images which is more than enough for a model to perform on. So randomly select only 467 negative images from the 20,000 available.  This is called under sampling and it works well. Another method is to use both undersampling and image augmentation. Example code to do this is shown below where I limit the number of images in the negative class to 1000, then create 533 augment images and add them to the positive class directory. NOTE- CAUTION the code below will delete images from your negative class directory and add augmented images to the positive class directory so before you run the code you might wish to create backups of these two directories so your original data is recoverable. In the demo code I had 1263 images in the positive directory and 467 images in the positive class directory. I tested the code and it works as desired. Now if your running a notebook on Kagle the code below will not work because you can not change the data in the input directories. So in that case you have to copy the input directories to the kagle working directory first. Then set the paths to those directories.

`````
!pip install -U albumentations
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os
import numpy as np
import random
import cv2
import albumentations as A
from tqdm import tqdm

def get_augmented_image(image): # this function returns an augmented version of the input img
    # see albumentations documentation at URL https://albumentations.ai/docs/getting_started/image_augmentation/
    # for information on various type of augmentations available these are examples below
    width=int(image.shape[1]*.8)
    height=int(image.shape[0]*.8)
    transform= A.Compose([
        A.HorizontalFlip(p=.5),
        A.RandomBrightnessContrast(p=.5),
        A.RandomGamma(p=.5),
        A.RandomCrop(width=width, height=height, p=.25) ])    
    return transform(image=image)['image']

negative_limit=1000
negative_dir_path=r'C:\Temp\data\trainup\negative'# path to directory holding the negative images
positive_dir_path=r'C:\Temp\data\trainup\positive' # path to directory holding positive images
negative_file_list=os.listdir(negative_dir_path)
positive_file_list=os.listdir(positive_dir_path)
sampled_negative_file_list=np.random.choice(negative_file_list, size=negative_limit, replace=False) 
for f in tqdm(negative_file_list, ncols=120, unit='files', colour='blue', desc='deleting excess neg files'): # this for loop leaves only 1000 images in the negative_image_directory
    if f not in sampled_negative_file_list:
        fpath=os.path.join(negative_dir_path,f)        
        os.remove(fpath)
# now create augmented images
delta=negative_limit-len(os.listdir(positive_dir_path)) # this is the number of augmented images to create to balance the dataset
sampled_positive_image_list=np.random.choice(positive_file_list, delta, replace=True) # replace=True because delta>number of positive images
i=0
for  f in tqdm(sampled_positive_image_list, ncols=120, unit='files', colour='blue',desc='creating augment images'): # this loop creates augmented images and stores them in the positive image directory
    fpath=os.path.join(positive_dir_path,f)
    img=cv2.imread(fpath)
    dest_file_name='aug' +str(i) + '-' + f # create the filename with a unique numeric prefix
    dest_path=os.path.join(positive_dir_path, dest_file_name) # store augmented images witha numeric prefix in the filename
    augmented_image=get_augmented_image(img)
    cv2.imwrite(dest_path, augmented_image)
    i +=1
# when these loops are done, the negative_image_directory will have 1000 images
# and the positive_image_directory will also have 1000 images, 533 of which are augmented images````
`````

In your code you have

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
```

change to

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
```

In model.comple remove (from_logits=True)